# How to user variables in docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, yaml

compose file as following:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php
    container_name: **my_container_name**
    .
    .
```

So I looking for method to put my initial values like this

```
version: '3.7'
**environment:
  - FOO=MyContainer
  - BAR=YourContainer**
services:
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php
    **container_name: ${FOO}**
    .
    .
    .
```

Something like top to define environment and some value in this and use it as container name

Comment: Why do you need this?  If you leave out this setting entirely, Compose will generate a name for you, and you can generally use `docker-compose` commands to manage containers without needing to know the specific name.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

In a file (e.g. `configrc`), you can set your variable:

```
FOO=my_value
```

Before executing a `docker-compose` command, you can run:

```
source ./configrc
```

Then, the `container_name` with the variable `FOO` should be taken into account when:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

**Solution 2**

Using a environment file, you can set default values for any environment variables referenced in the compose file. E.g. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

To be tested to check if it works for the `container_name`.